# Is there a way to send a user an invite to sign up using Firebase Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a react app with Firebase backend.
My app allows an admin to create an account (company). To add a user to the company, the admin enters their name and email address. I would like the added user to receive an email that requests them to create an account and they are automatically added to the inviter's company.

Does Firebase Auth allow you to do this? what could be the best approach to achieving this?

Comment: related?: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth?hl=es-419